# Plug in for tags

Tags: plugins, tags, customization

I need a plugin which fulfils all the requirement described in the image.

[I need something like this pre build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBk2I.png)

Comment: What front end framework are you using?

Comment: I'm working on alpine js